# Using "this" with multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I wasn't really sure how to word this in order to search ,to see if my question has been answered before.

Is there a way for me to consolidate these two statements into one by using "this"?

```
$("#rock1").click(function (event){
    $("#rock").css("background-image","url("+rock1.image+")")
    $('#flavorText').text(rock1.text);


});

$("#rock2").click(function (event){
    $("#rock").css("background-image","url("+rock2.image+")")
    $('#flavorText').text(rock2.text);



});
```

When I try to use "this.image" I've run into problems of it duplicating the image to places I don't want it and other images disappearing.

edit: Here is the other related code.

HTML

```
<div class="weapon rock1"  id="rock">


</div>

 <select>
    <option value="0" id="rock1"> Rock
    </option>
    <option class="hide" value="1" id="rock2"> Pet Rock
    </option>
 </select>
```

and

```
    var rock1 = {
type: "Beginner Rock",
text:"A rock.",
image: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=17i_dEIACd9TxrPEE13-jmzUrwpX5hsLt"
```

};

Comment: What is `rock1.text` & `rock2.text`.If they are objects please share that object too

Comment: Can you post the relevant HTML too?

Answer (score 1):

This is a sample example of how it can be done. `event` handlers can be added to  multiple selectors by putting them in a comma (`,`) separated string.

Use `event.target.id` to get the `id` of the clicked button

```js
var dataObj = {
  rock1: {
    image: "https://www.birdlife.org/sites/default/files/styles/1600/public/bialowieza_forest_c_tomasz_wilk_0.jpg?itok=iXRoJtoL",
    text: "Forest1"
  },
  rock2: {
    image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQudl_IoPOvhxPMaFRVl3UdBMuZ4MK63FF0Y4e1X7SYBGT2-rSnTQ",
    text: "Forest2"
  }
}

$("#rock1,#rock2").click(function(event) {
  var target = event.target.id;
  $("#rock").css("background-image", "url(" + dataObj[target].image + ")")
  $('#flavorText').text(dataObj[target].text);
});
```

```css
#rock {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="rock1">Rock 1</button>
<button id="rock2">Rock 2</button>


<div id="rock"></div>
<div id="flavorText">
  <div>
```

Alternatively you can also pass the `this.id` to a function from inline event handler

```js
var dataObj = {
  rock1: {
    image: "https://www.birdlife.org/sites/default/files/styles/1600/public/bialowieza_forest_c_tomasz_wilk_0.jpg?itok=iXRoJtoL",
    text: "Forest1"
  },
  rock2: {
    image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQudl_IoPOvhxPMaFRVl3UdBMuZ4MK63FF0Y4e1X7SYBGT2-rSnTQ",
    text: "Forest2"
  }
}

function updateDisp(id) {
  $("#rock").css("background-image", "url(" + dataObj[id].image + ")")
  $('#flavorText').text(dataObj[id].text);

}
```

```css
#rock {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="rock1" onclick="updateDisp(this.id)">Rock 1</button>
<button id="rock2" onclick="updateDisp(this.id)">Rock 2</button>


<div id="rock"></div>
<div id="flavorText">
  <div>
```